# Mysql converting double or int into a date or month

Tags: mysql, date, type-conversion, double

This might be a re-post, but I haven't been able to find anything that answers the question for me. I have a table with days listed as doubles like 435.6 or 5.2 and I need to convert this into a month. I've tried:

```
SELECT day FROM table WHERE DATE_ADD('2014-01-01', INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

But that query just spits out the same. Any help please.

Comment: What is the reference or starting date against which `435.6` days should be applied?  Can you show us sample input and output data?

Comment: for example: i want to use starting date 2014-01-01. So 'day' which holds a double type of value 32.5 should be converted to 2014-02-02 or when day is 0.0 it should convert to 2014-01-01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited version: 
Assuming your table is named `t` and your decimal column is named `d`

```
select date_format(date_add('2014-01-01', interval d day),"%m") from t;
```

This should add your epoch date (`'2014-01-01'`) and format the result as a number (00-12), after adding `d` days to the epoch. For the month represented as a word (January-December), use `"%M"`. [here's documentation for `DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

[here is a fiddle of the above code working for sample values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8800a1/8)

Comment: getting a syntax error at '), "%m")'

edit: yes, day table contains a bunch of decimals I need to convert to months.

Comment: That error was caused because the syntax of `date_add` is `date_add(**your_date**, **some_amount** **magnitude**)`, and using `day` as both a column and magnitude caused me to lose track. I've edited my proposed answer.

Comment: This is what I tried to use just as a sample run, SELECT day FROM tables WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAYS), "%m"); I'm getting an error near unexpected token  `('

Comment: Okay... what do you actually get if you try the answer I provided, and if that doesn't answer your question, why not/what error does it return? Changing the `WHERE` clause is not going to reformat the output.

Comment: it worked, but result was nothing. Just said Empty set 0.00 sec. Edit: When I try it with a lower case %m it just prints out the 1000 rows for me, but they remain as decimals.

Comment: Your code is `SELECT day where ___` my code is `SELECT date_format(...)` with no WHERE clause. Modifying the where clause the way you've done doesn't do anything-- it will return a result for any non-null date.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Next time, I'll try to get there faster and more clearly :-)  

Happy coding